# Android ListView, where new items push the old ones 'down'

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview

My app has a ListView where data is added from the top, automatically (through setData on a Adapter). When data is set, usually most of the data remains the same, and only a few items are added at the top. Typically tens of items exist, and 1-2 items are added at the top every ~10 seconds.

Right now the user experience sucks. It completely re-draws the list with the new data. If a user was reading an item just before data got updated, he will lose his old position and will need to scroll to find it again.

What I would like to see as a more human compatible transition / animation, where the old data gets pushed down, and new items are added at the top. Or - new data pushes old data 'down' - and I can see this animation.
(Something like a 'ticker' - only vertical, and items are on a listview.)

I went through ListViewAnimations, and JazzyListView. They are very nice, but they don't support my requirement.

I hate re-inventing the wheels, so after coming up empty I wanted to make sure there really isn't anything out there.

Answer (score 1):

> If a user was reading an item just before data got updated, he will
>   lose his old position and will need to scroll to find it again.

Before updating the list view remember the position and restore it.

Some thing like this:

```
private int position;
private void save(){
    position = myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
}
private void restore(){
    myListView.setSelection(position);
}
```

Comment: Hi. This is what I used until now, it's 'OKish' for a rough alpha, but not as a release. First off, unless the user is _exactly_ at the first pixel of the first visible position, then there's an error margin. In other words - the first visible position is half viewable). Also, I have some views that change their size, so the 'before' position is never the same as the 'after. Lastly, really when I think about it as a user - a human being, and what would seem as a natural transition - you would expect a slow scroll down and new items being added at the top (or bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You should check this, its from Android Developer page:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html#activity

Comment: Tried it. Very strange - some items animate, some don't. And it doesn't solve the problem - still, when 'setData' is called, the whole list of items gets wiped, and a new list gets drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to `getFirstVisiblePosition` before calling setData, then `setSelection` after.  That will still jump slightly (snapping to the current first visible item), unfortunately I believe you need to subclass ListView to access the pixel scroll value (`getScrollY` is for the view itself, not for scrolling inside it).

Maybe consider letting the user decide when to reload?  For instance, display a list header "3 new items, swipe down to refresh" or some such.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but see my answer to @Babibu